# Express app not serving static files on production server

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, static-files, unexpected-token

I'm building a simple (at least from a backend perspective) single page app using Express. This app is working perfectly well locally but after deploying it, my static files aren't working. I've looked around and I believe I am using express.static() correctly. The other thing to note, I've deployed it on GoDaddy. Not sure if this is causing any issue but perhaps relevant information.

Here's a link to my hosted site, feel free to inspect yourself: http://senseless.world/

My relevant code in my app.js file is the following (I've excluded a few unrelated bits):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname+'/static'));
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/static/index.ejs'), {routeStr: ''});
});
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
```

Here's how I'm loading static files in my index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Senseless World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/main.css?version=8" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/mobile-styles.css?version=3" type="text/css">
    <script src="/static/scripts/vendors/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/vendors/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/vendors/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bundle.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/modal-page-open.js?version=5"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/flashlight.js?version=3"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/senseless-favicon-16.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/senseless-favicon-32.png" type="image/png" sizes="32x32">
  </head>
...
```

The error I'm seeing in the console is the following:

[image]

And here is what I'm seeing from the network console:
[image]

---

Solved it:

Needed this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the network tab in the browser?

Comment: I've added it. Also, apologies the link I had included wasn't working before. The site should now be live.

Comment: Are you using some kind of module bundler? Or proxy in your host, like nginx?

Comment: When i try to access some static asset from your site(i.e.: `http://senseless.world/static/assets/images/lumen_lines.png`), i get a html file, it should serve an image. Looks like you are serving the `root` dir again.

Comment: can you post your nginx/apache config here?

Comment: I mostly followed this article to get my node app running on the goDaddy Servers: http://blog.codoplex.com/how-to-deploy-nodejs-app-in-godaddy-shared-hosting/

Comment: I didn't set up any nginx/apache configs. I am using browserfy, to bundle one of my javascript files so I can use a require statement (I'm being sloppy and not bundling everything into one, I have plans to do that but haven't gotten there yet).

Comment: @Danizavtz Yeah, I've noticed that too but can't figure out why everything is rendering that way? Do you have an idea why that might be happening based on the code I've shared?

Comment: Reading the tutorial, the unique thing that call my attention was the `.htaccess configuration`. But as I never worked with apache, don't know what should be next steps.

Comment: I can't see any warning or errors, if  you want to share the javascript error... If you try to access in incognito mode to make sure it is not a problem with cache. @MattVisco

Comment: @Danizavtz it's working now! Thanks for investigating. The p5 sound library wasn't working so I've removed it for now and that allowed my other scripts to work. Will fix that later.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow This Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

// At first create public folder and move all ejs file in public folder
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname+'/static'));
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render(path.join(index.ejs);
});
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You've removed the path and '' notation for my index.ejs file (which in in my /static folder).

Additionally, I am passing a variable to my index.ejs so I need to include the  {routeStr: ''} bit from above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nginx on a Digitalocean's vp server, edit your Nginx config file.

Run the following commands:

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
2. remove or comment out `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`
3. close the editor and test your nginx config with `sudo nginx -t`
4. if the test succeeds, restart nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

That's it. Check your app again.